# Clearfixing floats inside the container but ignoring floats outside the container?

Tags: html, css, sass, clearfix

I've got the following HTML structure:

```
%aside.sidebar

%main

  %article
    %h2
    %aside.picture
      %img
    %p

  %article
    %h2
    %aside.picture
      %img
    %p
```

(If you're not familiar with HAML: the structure above represents an HTML tree. `%aside.picture` means `<aside class='picture'>`.)

The sidebar is tall and is floated to the left.

Within articles, images are also floated to the left.

I would like to clearfix articles in such a manner that each article's height grows up to the bottom of its image, but not to the bottom of the sidebar.

Please have a look at a demo: http://sassmeister.com/gist/9173268

Note that the first article's clearfix made it grow as tall as sidebar is. But i only want it to grow as tall as the image.

*PS* `overflow: hidden` does the trick, but lets assume that article contain popup elements that should be able to appear outside of their containers?

Comment: Would overflow:auto work?

Comment: Are you opposed to having the sidebar be as tall as your main element?

Comment: Do you want text of each article to stay on the right of image and create a column? (thus text isn't just flowing around the floating image as usual)

Answer (score 1):

Setting each article to inline-block (and giving it full width) may work:

```
article {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vKF83/

Answer (score 0):

Pixel's answer does work at your demo link provided: http://sassmeister.com/gist/9173268

Simply put in your Sass window the following in the article selector (without the semi-colons):

```
display: inline-block
width: 100%
```

You could also specify the height if you wanted of course within that same block:

```
height: 300px
```